# An idea to compute the following integral $ \int_0^1 s^a (1-s)^b e^{-c/s} \, ds$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Someone has an idea to calculate the following integral
$$I_{a,b,c} = \int_{0}^{1} s^{a} (1-s)^b e^{-\frac{c}{s}} \, ds; \quad  a<0, \mbox{and}\, b,c>0.$$
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure you have nothing more to say about the parameters? It would be helpful to know, for example, if $|a|>|b|$ or $|a|<|b|$

Comment: i got a hypergeometric function

Comment: let $s = 1/t$ , $ds = -1/t^2 dt$

$$I_{a,b,c} = \displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty} t^{-a-b-2} (t-1)^b e^{-ct} \, dt \quad  a<0, \mbox{and}\, b,c>0.$$

The exponential decays quickly so you can use a quadrature method if you need to calculate a value.

Comment: $I_{a,b,c}$ is a hypergeometric function given in "Gradshteyn, I. S., & Ryzhik, I. M. (2014). Table of integrals, series, and products. Academic press."p. 339.  @@@Thank you.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to finding the Laplace transform of $$\frac{t^b}{(1+t)^{a+b+2}}$$ that if $a,b$ are integers is easy to compute through integration by parts. Otherwise, the Tricomi hypergeometric function $U$ gives the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^1s^a(1-s)^be^{-\frac{c}{s}}~ds$

$=\int_\infty^1\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^a\left(1-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^be^{-ct}~d\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)$

$=\int_1^\infty t^{-a-b-2}(t-1)^be^{-ct}~dt$

$=\int_0^\infty(t+1)^{-a-b-2}t^be^{-c(t+1)}~d(t+1)$

$=e^{-c}\int_0^\infty t^b(t+1)^{-a-b-2}e^{-ct}~dt$

$=e^{-c}~\Gamma(b+1)U(b+1,-a,c)$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations)